# Inline-block elements in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My HTML code looks like this and I can NOT edit it:

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
}

.innero1 {
  display: flex;
}

.one,
.two,
.inner2,
.inner3 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.two {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.inner2,
.inner3 {
  margin-left: 3px;
  height: max-content;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="innero1">
    <div class="inner1">
      <div class="one">Text1</div>
      <div class="one">Text2</div>
      <div class="one">Text3</div>
      <div class="one">Text4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner2">Text5</div>
    <div class="inner3">Text6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="innero2">
    <div class="four">
      <ul>
        <li class="two">Text7</li>
        <li class="two">Text8</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the `div` do not behave like typical inline-blocks.

What I want to achieve is to make it look like this (when resized they jump to the next line):

```css
.one {
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">Text1</div>
  <div class="one">Text2</div>
  <div class="one">Text3</div>
  <div class="one">Text4</div>
  <div class="one">Text5</div>
  <div class="one">Text6</div>
  <div class="one">Text7</div>
  <div class="one">Text8</div>
</div>
```

I was thinking of using jQuery `detach`, but don't think it's very good idea...

EDIT:
I DO NOT want to change my html. The final effect should work like in the second snippet, but do not look like it (code)...

Comment: You should set a height to div element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you just remove the flexboxes and set all the intermediate containers to `display:inline`? Like this.

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
}

.inner1, .innero1, .innero2, .four {
  display: inline;
}

.one,
.two,
.inner2,
.inner3 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.two {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0px;
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="innero1">
    <div class="inner1">
      <div class="one">Text1</div>
      <div class="one">Text2</div>
      <div class="one">Text3</div>
      <div class="one">Text4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner2">Text5</div>
    <div class="inner3">Text6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="innero2">
    <div class="four">
      <ul>
        <li class="two">Text7</li>
        <li class="two">Text8</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I knew someone smarter than me and better at css would have a quick and easy solution that doesn't require JS. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Well, you are 100% right. It works + it's much easier than JS method from below (but it also works!)

Answer (score 0):

Without the entire site to look at it's hard to debug css issues but based on the [first fiddle you posted](https://jsfiddle.net/1bzxyvam/) adding this css to the bottom of the css had it working

```
.container{
  display: inline-block;
}
.innero1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.innero1 div, .container div {
  float: left; 
  margin-right: .5em;
  display: inline-block;
}
.one { 
  float: left; 
  margin-right: .5em
}
```

If that doesn't solve you problem let me know and i will see if can help more.

**EDIT/Update:**

Make sure you add the class I highlighted with the comment in the css. Below is a snippet and [here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1bzxyvam/43/)

```js
var lst = $('<div class="stack" />');

$('.one, .inner2, .inner3, .two').each(function(i, v){
  $('<div />').html($(v).html()).appendTo(lst);
});

$('.innero1, .innero2').hide();

lst.appendTo($('.container'));
```

```css
.container {
 background-color: red;
 display: flex;
}

.container {
 background-color: red;
}

.innero1 {
  display: flex;
}

.one,
.two,
.inner2,
.inner3 {
 border: 2px solid black;
 display: inline-block;
}

.two {
 list-style-type: none;
}

.inner2,
.inner3 {
 margin-left: 3px;
 height: max-content;
}

ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding-left: 3px;
}


/* Add this class to your css */
.stack div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: .25em
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="innero1">
    <div class="inner1">
        <div class="one">Text1</div>
        <div class="one">Text2</div>
        <div class="one">Text3</div>
        <div class="one">Text4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner2">Text5</div>
    <div class="inner3">Text6</div>
  </div>

  <div class="innero2">
      <div class="four">
           <ul>
              <li class="two">Text7</li>
              <li class="two">Text8</li>
           </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well, it looks better, but it doesn't work like in the snippet 2. Spaces between elements are changed and `Text5` and `Text6` jumps into other line than `Text7` and `Text8`.

Comment: Without being able to modify the actual HTML then i _think_ this is as close as you can get. Someone smarter than me and better with CSS might be able to make it work. You have to remember that the elements you want to 'stack' are all part of different containers.

Comment: If you can run some javascript to modify the elements let me know and I can write something to help properly structure the HTML so that the stacking works like it is shown in snippet2.

Comment: Yeah, I know elements are parts of different containers. That's the point. And sure, I can run javascript and anything, just cannot modify html.

Comment: @wpwpwp I updated the answer with a better solution. If this solves your problem please don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @wpwpwp no problem. If you wouldn't mind marking it as the accepted answer that would help me out and allow me to help more people.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you are not using the `flex-wrap: wrap` property. If you want to have elements break (like typical html/css) then you need to tell it to wrap.

Here is a super basic example:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start
}

.item {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>
  <div class="item">13</div>
  <div class="item">14</div>
  <div class="item">15</div>
</div>
```

I think this answers your question...if not please clarify a bit more. You SHOULD NOT need JavaScript to do what your asking.

Comment: Is this making the boxes stretch on the second row?

Comment: Ignore second snippet. It just shows how it should WORK. Someone edited it and it misleads ppl. My html shouldn't be edited. You are right about `flex-wrap: wrap`, but for example, in `ul` it would wrap 2 elements at once, and I want them go one by one.

Comment: Boxes are not stretched on the second row...I just didn't add a min-width so the 2 digit numbers will be a bit wider as I am only using padding. I think it may be helpful to fully understand what your practical application for this HTML structure is. Is the UL a separate element (like a menu)? It feels a little like maybe the structure is off. Could you explain a bit more? Also, you will need to specify the justify-content part (something I didn't point out initially).